# onSelectSlot Mobile React Big Calendar

Tags: reactjs, react-big-calendar

When I am trying to use React Big Calendar on mobile browser, I can't use the onSelectSlot function. I can click the events but can't click the timeslots for open a new event modal. No error on console too.

Here is my code. I used longPressThreshold but didn't work.

```
<DragAndDropCalendar
            date={defaultDate}
            onNavigate={(date) => setDefaultDate(date)}
            onEventDrop={moveEvent}
            selectable={true}
            formats={formats}
            messages = {{week: 'Hafta', day: 'Gün', month: 'Ay', previous: 'Geri', next: 'İleri', today: 'Bugün', showMore: function(e) {return '+' + e + ' daha'}}}
            events={eventsList}
            onSelecting={slot => false}
            localizer={localizer}
            view={view}
            showMultiDayTimes={false}
            onView={(e) => setView(e)}
            views={['day', 'week', 'month']}
            step={calendarTimeCell}
            culture={'tr'}
            min={new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(), new Date().getDate(), 7, 0)}
            max={new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(), new Date().getDate(), 21, 0)}
            onSelectEvent={event => {
                let endDate = moment(event.endDate);
                let startDate = moment(event.startDate)
                openEditAppointmentModal(event, customerData, moment.duration(endDate.diff(startDate)).asMinutes())
            }}
            longPressThreshold={10}
            onSelectSlot={openNewAppointmentModal}
            tooltipAccessor={(event) => appointmentTooltip(event, resourceIdAccessor)}
            resources={view === 'week' ? null : resources}
            resourceAccessor={view === 'week' ? null : (event) => resourceIdAccessor === 'serviceId' ? event.serviceId : event.teammateId}
            resourceIdAccessor={view === 'week' ? null : resourceIdAccessor}
            resourceTitleAccessor={view === 'week' ? null : 'resource_name'}
            titleAccessor={(event) => appointmentTitleAccessor(event, view)}
            startAccessor={(event) => new Date(event.startDate)}
            endAccessor={(event) => new Date(event.endDate)}
            eventPropGetter={(event, start, end, isSelected) => eventStyleGetter(event, start, end, isSelected)}
        />
```

EDIT: I can click the timeslots clearly in MONTH VIEW. But Week and Day View is not working for onSelectSlot.

Answer (score 0):

I solved with this codesandbox! https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-brattain-8wjh6?file=/src/CalendarMobile.js

Answer (score 0):

I'm also was using `onSelecting={slot => false}`, but then I replaced this with:

```
onSelecting={(props) => {
                        if(document.documentElement.clientWidth <= 768 ) {
                            handleSelectSlot(props)

                        }
                                                
                        return false;
                    }}
```